# JW Player, I am trying to create a live stream radio using existing mp3 files

Tags: php, jwplayer, live-streaming, playlist

I am trying to create a live radio using the existing mp3 files (I have the links saved in a MYSQL database). Using a player like jw player, or any player that can suit my needs. Is there any ways that a PHP script can generate a random playlist for a user and as he reach the end of that playlist, the script would generate another playlist and continue playing without stopping.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the JWPlayer Javascript API to update the file that's being played by JW.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference

Answer (score 1):

Why not use one of the many existing software packages for doing this?  Take a look at [Ices](http://www.icecast.org/docs/ices-2.0.0/basic.html), or one of the many other SHOUTcast auto-dj programs.